# Как использовать условный оператор if при проверке введенных данных?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, if, qt-designer

Есть задача, в которой условия прописаны тем, что надо выбрать индекс переменной, 
то есть умножение при выборе значения индекса `1, 2, 3, ...` на соответствующее из значений `1000, 100, 10, ...`

Не понимаю, как учитывать условие в данной ситуации, он его просто не воспринимает.

**main.py**

```
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    
    from gert import Ui_MainWindow
    import sys
    
    
    class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(mywindow, self).__init__()
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            # подключение клик-сигнал к слоту btnClicked
            self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
    
        def btnClicked(self):
    
            x = self.ui.textEdit_2.toPlainText()
            y = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()
    
            if y == 1:
    
                    z = float(x)
                    self.ui.lineEdit.setText(f" {z:.0f}")
    
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = mywindow()
    application.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**gert.py**

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    
    
    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(777, 484)
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
            self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-160, -120, 1281, 901))
            self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
            self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 270, 121, 31))
            self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 280, 151, 16))
            self.label.setObjectName("label")
            self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 230, 121, 31))
            self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
            self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 151, 16))
            self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
            self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 181, 111))
            self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
            self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 60, 71, 16))
            self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
            self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 80, 81, 16))
            self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
            self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 100, 71, 16))
            self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
            self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 120, 51, 16))
            self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
            self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 0, 351, 41))
            self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
            self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 250, 141, 31))
            self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
            self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 260, 47, 13))
            self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
            self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 140, 71, 16))
            self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
            self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 370, 121, 41))
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
            self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 777, 21))
            self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
            MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
            self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
            self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
            MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    
            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    
        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
            self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите значение индекса:"))
            self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Количественная единица:"))
            self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Значение индексов:"))
            self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1)килограммы"))
            self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2)милиграммы"))
            self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3)граммы"))
            self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4)тонны"))
            self.textEdit_3.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
    "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
    "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
    "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Антон Корнеенков ИВТ-12 Вариант-6</span></p></body></html>"))
            self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Итог:"))
            self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5)центнеры"))
            self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вычислить"))
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен что правильно понял вас, но попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


#from gert import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(777, 484)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-160, -120, 1281, 901))
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 270, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 280, 151, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 230, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 151, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 181, 111))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 60, 71, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 80, 81, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 100, 71, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 120, 51, 16))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 0, 351, 41))
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 250, 141, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 260, 47, 13))
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 140, 71, 16))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 370, 121, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 777, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите значение индекса:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Количественная единица:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Значение индексов:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1)килограммы"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2)милиграммы"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3)граммы"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4)тонны"))
        self.textEdit_3.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Антон Корнеенков ИВТ-12 Вариант-6</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Итог:"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5)центнеры"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вычислить"))
  

# --> v v
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        # подключение клик-сигнал к слоту btnClicked
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
        
        self.ui.textEdit_2.setFocus()

    def btnClicked(self):
        x = self.ui.textEdit_2.toPlainText()
        y = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()

        if not y or not x:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Заполните поля необходимые для расчета.'
            )
            self.ui.textEdit_2.setFocus()
            self.ui.lineEdit.clear()
            return
            
        try:
            z = float(x)
        except:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Количественная единица может принимать значениен \n'
                'или целое число или число с плавающей запятой.'
            )
            self.ui.textEdit_2.setFocus()
            self.ui.lineEdit.clear()
            return
# ------------> v v <---- !!! +++
        if y == '1':
            self.ui.lineEdit.setText(f" {z * 1000:.0f}")
        elif y == '2':
            self.ui.lineEdit.setText(f" {z * 100:.0f}")
        elif y == '3':     
            self.ui.lineEdit.setText(f" {z * 10:.0f}")
#        elif y == '4':
#            ...
#        ...
        else:          
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Вы ввели неправильное значение индекса.'
            )
            self.ui.textEdit.setFocus()
            self.ui.lineEdit.clear() 
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, вы меня абсолютно правильно поняли, я просто не так опытен, как Вы, но огромное Вам спасибо, у меня появляется больше мотивации учиться, теперь я знаю, как это работает, Благодарю Вас

Comment: @ИванИванов Я рад, что вам помогают мои ответы. Закатите рукава и вперед, и все у вас получится.